# When I run this code in jgrasp there is no output and the code doesn't end

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Lesson_30_Activity {

    public static String [] list = {"every", " near  ing ", "      checking", "food ", "stand", "value      "};

public static void main(String[] args)
 {
 String s=null;
 for(int i =0;i<list.length;i++){

 for(int j =0;j<list[i].length();j++){

 if(list[i].charAt(j)!=' '){
  s =s+list[i].charAt(j);


 }

 list[i]=list[i]+s;     
 }

 s=null;
 System.out.println(list[i]); 

 }
 }
}
```

I think that either the for loop I'am using isn't stopping and one of them isn't stopping or the varibale s isn't being added to the position in the list[i].

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the inner loop can keep making the string that it is iterating longer.

Comment: Stephen C regarding your comment, are you meaning that the second for loop is just making the code go on forever without doing anything or the first for loop is doing that.

Comment: The former.  You never reach the string's `length()` because the `length()` keeps increasing

Answer (score 0):

When you run into a situation like this, to see what is going on either use the debugger and step through the code or add print statements.

For example, after:

```
list[i]=list[i]+s;
```

add

```
System.out.println("i " + i + " j " + j + " list[i] " + list[i]);
```